# how to conditionally update table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have one address table (containing k_id-PK, address) and one add_hist log table(containing k_id, address,change date) i.e. it has all address per id and on which date address change.

I want to make an update query which will update address column in address table so,fetching latest address from add_hist table will do the job.I am almost done with my query. Its fetching correct result too. But I want if address table is already updated, then dont update it.Here goes my query.Please review and correct it to get the desired result.

```
update address a set k_add =
(select kad from (
select h.k_id kid, h.k_add kad, h.chg_dt from add_hist h, 
(select k_id, max(chg_dt) ch from add_hist 
group by k_id
) h1 
where h1.k_id = h.k_id
and h1.ch=h.chg_dt
) h2
where h2.kid = a.k_id)
;
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a way of directly you doing that check in a single update statement. You'd have to first keep the kad output (from the subquery) in a variable, and then only perform the update if that value is indeed different from the one that's in the table.

Comment: Thank u Renato :)

Comment: @RenatoAfonso - for your future Official Oracle Training sessions: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201706230023201170024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a merge instead of an update:

```
merge into address a
using (
  select k_id, max(k_add) keep (dense_rank last order by chg_dt) as k_add
  from add_hist
  group by k_id
) h
on (a.k_id = h.k_id)
when matched then
  update set a.k_add = h.k_add
  where (a.k_add is null and h.k_add is not null)
  or (a.k_add is not null and h.k_add is null)
  or a.k_add != h.k_add;
```

The query in the `using` clause finds the most recent address for each ID from the history table. When a matching ID exists on the main table that is updated - but only if the value is different, because of the `where` clause.

With some dummy data:

```
create table address (k_id number primary key, k_add varchar2(20));
create table add_hist (k_id number, k_add varchar2(20), chg_dt date);

insert into address (k_id, k_add) values (1, 'Address 1');
insert into address (k_id, k_add) values (2, 'Address 2');
insert into address (k_id, k_add) values (3, null);
insert into address (k_id, k_add) values (4, null);

insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (1, 'Address 1', date '2017-01-01');
insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (1, 'Address 2', date '2017-01-02');
insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (1, 'Address 1', date '2017-01-03');

insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (2, 'Address 1', date '2017-01-01');
insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (2, 'Address 2', date '2017-01-02');
insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (2, 'Address 3', date '2017-01-03');

insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (3, 'Address 1', date '2017-01-01');
insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (3, null, date '2017-01-02');

insert into add_hist (k_id, k_add, chg_dt) values (4, 'Address 1', date '2017-01-01');

commit;
```

running your update statement gets:

```
4 rows updated.

select * from address;

      K_ID K_ADD               
---------- --------------------
         1 Address 1           
         2 Address 3           
         3                     
         4 Address 1
```

After rolling back to the starting state, running the merge gets:

```
2 rows merged.

select * from address;

      K_ID K_ADD               
---------- --------------------
         1 Address 1           
         2 Address 3           
         3                     
         4 Address 1
```

Same final result, but 1 row merged rather than 2 rows updated.

(If you run the merge without the `where` clause, all four rows are still affected; without the null checks only row with ID 2 is updated).

Comment: Thank u so much Alex for taking so much trouble...i was stucked...Its indeed a great help :)

Comment: Exactly the same result (and with almost the same syntax) can be achieved with an `update`. Note that the `where` clause should handle `null` as well (unless `not null` constraints exist on the "address" columns, which is often not the case).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result with an `UPDATE` statement. Specifically, you need to "update through a join." The syntax has to be precise though. [Update with joins](https://web.archive.org/web/20170915123941/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins)

Using the same setup as in Alex's answer, the following `update` statement will update one row.

**EDIT**: See Alex Poole's comments below this Answer. The solution proposed here will work only in Oracle 12.1 and above. The problem is not the "update through join" concept, but the source rowset being the result of an aggregation. It has to do with the way in which Oracle knows, at compile time, that the "join" column in the source rowset is unique (it has no duplicates). In older versions of Oracle, an explicit unique or primary key constraint or index was required. Of course, when we `GROUP BY <col>`, the `<col>` will be unique in the result set of an aggregation, but it will not have a unique constraint or index on it. It seems Oracle recognized this situation, and since 12.1 it allows `update through join` where the source table is the result of an aggregation, as shown in this example.

```
update
  ( select a.k_add as current_address, q.new_address
    from   (
             select   k_id, 
                      min(k_add) keep (dense_rank last order by chg_dt) as new_address
             from     add_hist
             group by k_id
           )       q
           join
           address a  on a.k_id = q.k_id
  )
set   current_address = new_address
where current_address != new_address 
   or current_address is null and new_address is not null
   or current_address is not null and new_address is null
;
```

Comment: Thanks @mathguy...its really nice to know different ways of finding result

Comment: This works in 12cR1 (and presumably R2, but can't check), but still gets ORA-01779 in 11gR2 with my dummy table. In 10gR2 adding a `bypass_ujvc` hint (undocumented!) 'fixes' it, but that doesn't seem to work any more in 11gR2. OP might get different results with their own tables, and/or might be in 12c, of course...

Comment: @AlexPoole - Interesting! The main difference between `merge` and `update through join` is the uniqueness of the join column in the source table: `update` requires that it be "known" at compile time, while `merge` only checks at runtime. I didn't actually try but I am almost sure the example I wrote up in the Documentation article works in older versions of Oracle (the join column is explicitly declared PK in the source table). I didn't know, before I posted this Answer, if it will work when the source table is the result of an aggregate subquery, but it did. (continued)

Comment: It didn't occur to me that this relaxation of the restriction on `update through join` only works in 12.1. Thank you for trying it on other versions!

Comment: @mathguy - I did check the example you added to docs in 11gR2 and 10gR2  too, and it did work in both *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole - thank you for checking that, too! I edited my Answer to clarify that the solution only works in 12.1 and above.